# Bitbucket pipeline global function

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have pipeline like below

```
definitions:
  steps:
    common_function: &common_function |
      if [ "$BITBUCKET_BRANCH" == "master" ]; then
       echo "steps"
      fi

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Step1
          size: 2x 
          runs-on: 
            - 'scanner.scanner'
          script:
            if some condition; then
                  common_function
              fi
```

but the common_function is not getting called and getting the below error. I tried with * as well.

```
if [ -n "$bugs" ] || [ -n "$vulnerabilities" ] || [ "$status" = "ERROR" ]; then
   common_function
fi
bash: common_function: command not found
```

Can someone help

```
if [ -n "$bugs" ] || [ -n "$vulnerabilities" ] || [ "$status" = "ERROR" ]; then
   common_function
fi
bash:common_function: command not found
```

Comment: You are defining a YAML anchor, not a global function: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/

Comment: Would you please fix the format in code blocks?